# Does JPA's persist call differentiate between entity with a single PK column and an entity with composite PK?

Tags: java, jpa, persist

we have two entities in our system as follows:

- Invoice: [InvoiceID, OrgID] is the primary key represented as a bean and associated with Invoice using `@IdClass` annotation
- WorkflowStates: `WorkflowStateId` is the primary key column defined using `@Id` annotation.

In both the entities, the ID fields (InvoiceID, WorkflowStateId) are auto generated using a DB sequence.

While calling persist on a newly created instance of Invoice, when we set the InvoiceID to `-1`, the instance is persisted and ID is properly generated.

But while calling persist on a newly created instance of WorkflowStates with WorkflowStateID set to `-1`, the `persist()` call throws an exception:

```
 org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: <Entity Class>
```

I couldn't find much in the search, if there is any difference in the way `persist()` method works for entities with single column as PK and for entities with composite PK. Does anyone know more on this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you got this exception because you assign an id to your persistent, and at the same time you specify in your mapping that the id is auto-generated.

When you do the persist(), hibernate do the assumption that this object already exists in your DB (based on the fact that your object already have an Id)... but it's not the case. That's why you get the exception.

So, I suggest you to remove all your setId(-1). (keep the id null before persisting the object)

**EDIT**

There are some differences in the way hibernate detect if an entity is persistent or not whenever the entity have a Single Id column or a Compound Id. (I know it because I look at the code, I didn't find anything in the doc).

I suggest you to put a breakpoint in `DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist` and see what's going on. Or enable hibernate debug logging and analyze it.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, why didn't this happen for the Invoice entity?

Comment: Without exact code its impossible to say anything definitive.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `@IdClass` makes the difference because in fact invoice doesn't have "id column". It has composite key, so the InvoiceId will not be generated. The value you provide as invoiceId will be used during the persist operation (in this case -1). So the "Id" of Invoice will be combination of 2 values that you provide (invoiceId & orgId), hibernate will not override them with generated values it will just use the given values.

I don't know the code so it's hard to me to tell something more.
If you could provide code example it would help a lot.